# <IonReactRouter> Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to fix this problem?

Creating a React Application, App.tsx fails. Basically copy/pasted the example from here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation

[image]

Full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/react';

import Main from './pages/Main';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Cash from './pages/Cash';
import CashDetail from './pages/CashDetail';
import Securities from './pages/Securities';
import SecurityDetail from './pages/SecurityDetail';
import SecurityAmountDetail from './pages/SecurityAmountDetail';
import ClientList from './pages/ClientList';
import Totals from './pages/Totals';
import ReportPerformanceAdHoc from './pages/ReportPerformanceAdHoc';
import { store } from './utils/Store';

import '@ionic/core/css/core.css';
import '@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';

/* Internationalization Support */
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';

import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';

export default class App extends React.PureComponent<{},{}> {

  render (){
    return (
    <IntlProvider locale="de-CH">
        <IonApp>
          <IonReactRouter>
            <IonRouterOutlet>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={ Login } />
              <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
                if( store.userIsLoggedIn ){
                  return (<Redirect to="/main" />);
                }
                return (<Redirect to="/login" />);
              }} />

              <Route exact path="/main" component={ Main } />
              <Route exact path="/main/client-list" component={ ClientList } />
              <Route exact path="/main/cash" component={ Cash } />
              <Route exact path="/main/cashdetail" component={ CashDetail } />
              <Route exact path="/main/securities" component={ Securities } />
              <Route exact path="/main/securitydetail" component={ SecurityDetail } />
              <Route exact path="/main/securityamountdetail" component={ SecurityAmountDetail } />
              <Route exact path="/main/totals" component={ Totals } />
              <Route exact path="/main/report/performance-adhoc" component={ ReportPerformanceAdHoc } />
            </IonRouterOutlet>
          </IonReactRouter>
        </IonApp>
      </IntlProvider>
    );
  }
}
```